# Expectation of squared error

Tags: machine-learning, least-squares

In machine learning, we let $X$ be a real-valued input vector and $Y$ be a real number output, with joint distribution $P(X,Y)$. We are looking for a function $f(X)$ for predicting $Y$ given the values of $X$. In most of machine learning problems, we give penalty for each time that the prediction is wrong. The loss function is defined as follows:  $L(Y,f(X))=(Y-f(X))^2$.

The expected square prediction error is given as:

$$EPE(f) = E(Y-f(X))^2 = \displaystyle\int [y-f(x)]^2P(dx,dy). $$

---

The book I'm reading says: By conditioning on $X$, we can write EPE as $EPE(f) = E_XE_{Y|X}((Y-f(X))^2|X)$, and eventually getting a solution that is $f(x) = E(Y|X=x)$.

I'm not sure I follow what happened in these steps. Please help me with the derivation. 
Thanks

Comment: drawn from rephrased question: If, given an input x , the label y is probabilistic according to some distribution P (y|x) then the **optimal prediction to minimize** the squared loss is to predict the expected value, h(x) = E_{P(y|x)}[y].

Answer (score 5):

The expected value of $(Y-a)^2$ is given by
$$E[(Y-a)^2] = E\left[(Y-E[Y])^2\right] + \left(E[Y]-a\right)^2 = \operatorname{var}(Y) + \left(E[Y]-a\right)^2.\tag{1}$$ 
Regarded as a function of $a$, the smallest possible value
of $E[(Y-a)^2]$ is $\operatorname{var}(Y)$, and this minimum
value occurs exactly when $a$ equals $E[Y]$.

Now, when it is known that $X$ has value $x$, 
all the above applies in exactly the same
way except that we are now looking at the *conditional* EPE
$E[(Y-a)^2\mid X = x]$ instead of the unconditional EPE $E[(Y-a)^2]$.
Conditioning *everything* on $X=x$, the formula $(1)$ becomes
$$\begin{align}
E[(Y-a)^2\mid X=x] &= E\left[\left(Y-E[Y\mid X=x]\right)^2\mid X=x\right] 
+ \left(E[Y\mid X=x]-a\right)^2\\
&= \operatorname{var}(Y\mid X=x) + \left(E\left[Y\mid X=x\right]-a\right)^2
\end{align}$$
Thus, the minimum value of $E[(Y-a)^2\mid X =x]$ occurs when $a$ is chosen
to be the *conditional* mean $E[Y\mid X = x]$ of $Y$ instead of the 
unconditional mean $E[Y]$. The minimum *conditional EPE* is, of course,
the *conditional* variance $\operatorname{var}(Y\mid X=x)$ of $Y$
given $X = x$ instead of the *unconditional* variance 
$\operatorname{var}(Y)$.